# Would an array of the same type of objects as the class it is a member of create infinite instances?

Tags: c++, arrays

Sorry for the awkward wording of the question but I'm not sure how to describe it better in words so I'll try an example

```
struct A {
    A* a;
    A() {a = new A[2];}
    ~A() {delete[] a;}
}

int main() {
    A aa;
}
```

Once `aa` gets constructed, the `*a` internal to `struct A` will be allocated an array of two `A` objects. But it appears to me that each of those objects will, in turn, create an array of `A` objects of their own as a result of the default constructor, and on and on in a seemingly endless cycle. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: Ah, why dont you try?

Comment: You assumption is correct as you basically declared a recursive constructor.

Comment: It never crossed my mind that constructors could be called recursively. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: @Manuel We they can but they can't.  the standard forbids it so it should not be done.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I correct in thinking this?

Yes. The constructor is called recursively, and you'll probably run out of dynamic storage or overflowing the call stack at some point.

Comment: I have a feeling the call stack will be exhausted well before the memory pool for dynamic allocations is.

Comment: @NathanOliver The call stack is only occupied once.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to optimize this program into a call to `std::terminate`, I think. I'm not sure, but it may even be undefined behavior to unconditionally, recursively call the same function.

Comment: Yeah?  You never leave the constructor before you call it again.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That sounds reasonable.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah, you mean the call stack frames. Yes, could likely be.

Comment: The spec says "If a program contains no violations of the rules in this International Standard, a conforming implementation shall, within its resource limits, accept and correctly execute2 that program.". I think undounded recursive calls exceeds the resource limits of any implementation, so this inevitably causes UB.

Comment: @Johannes would you mind to edit this into my answer, or provide another one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are absolutely right. Your code effectively embeds an array of objects inside itself. Essentially, you are making this impossible `struct`:

```
struct A {
    A a[2]; // Impossible
};
```

Your code bypasses compiler's check for by using pointers, so the code crashes at runtime due to infinite recursion.

If you would like to make `A` that refers to two `A`s optionally, make an array of two pointers.